# Bigvideo background with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

i'm using this plugin:
http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/

It's working good but the problem is that I need to have the video with a link, so the user can click on it and enters the site.

This is the [website](http://diegoesteban.comlu.com/aa/)

This is the code i'm using:

```
     <!-- BigVideo -->
    <script src="js/bigvideo.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var BV = new $.BigVideo();
            BV.init();
            BV.show('video/video.mp4');
        });
    </script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<script src="js/bigvideo.js"></script>
    <script>
        var BV;
        $(function() {
            BV = new $.BigVideo();

        });

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick='BV.init(); BV.show(\'video/video.mp4\');'> Play Video </a>
```

See if thats working.

Comment: It doesn't work, I updated the site with your solution

Comment: place script above your <a> tag as I did so onclicking bv should have new $.BigVideo() initialized.